# Destructuring assignment default value from promise

Tags: javascript, async-await, destructuring

When providing default values for destructuring assignments, something that I haven't seen spoken about is using `await` to provide the value from a promise, like so:

```js
// Inside an asynchronous function, where `person` is an object...

const { 
  name = "Alex",
  age = await getAge(),
} = person;
```

I've tested this, and while it seems to work, I'm curious if it goes against some best-practices or if there is any other information out there as to why this shouldn't be done.

It's much handier than assigning to a mutable variable and re-initializing it later on, provided that async errors are caught correctly.

Comment: I don't see any issue with this apart from future maintainers wondering why the default value is async

Comment: Haha, touché — my use-case is mainly for an annoying situation where abstraction is useful, but as you point out probably not a great habit to get into...